# Look inside pattern if parent pattern matches and share chars between patterns

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

I have a string like this:

> Tickets order: № 123123123. CED-MSW-RPG-MOW-CEK PODYLOVA/ALEMR 555
>   423578932 19OCT11 Tickets order: № 123123123. 346257.
>   CSK-MOW-PRG-MOW-CWQ PODYLOVA/ALEMR 555 45837043 19OCT11

I need to collect all codes that are CEK, MOW, PRG and so on. I tried this pattern firstly:

```
$pattern = '#[-|\s]([A-Z]{3})#';
```

As result a get all my codes (that's ok) and the first 3 chars of users surname: "POD" from "PODYLOVA". If i say "after my code must be an hyphen or free space char by changing my pattern to this:

```
$pattern = '#[-|\s]([A-Z]{3})[-|\s]#';
```

My $matches var has this:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => ' CED-',
    1 => '-RPG-',
    2 => '-CEK ',
    3 => ' CSK-',
    4 => '-PRG-',
    5 => '-CWQ ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 'CED',
    1 => 'RPG',
    2 => 'CEK',
    3 => 'CSK',
    4 => 'PRG',
    5 => 'CWQ',
  ),
)
```

You can see, that my pattern doesn't "share" the hyphen between desired codes.

I see two solutions, but cannot imaging the pattern, which will suit:

1. Make the pattern to share the hyphen between codes
2. Make more complicated pattern: firstly collect the text which contains codes ("CED-MSW-RPG-MOW-CEK") and then get all #([A-Z]{3}# inside this pattern.

It seems, that solution#1 is the best in my case, but how it should look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`\b([A-Z]{3})\b`

HTH

Comment: You don't even need the parentheses anymore. And you might want to give a hint to @the_ghost that `\b` is a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: Thanks you! I was just walking around this pattern and even tried \b but didn't think that everything is so easy

Answer (score 0):

does this give you what you want?

```
(?<=-|\s)[A-Z]{3}(?=-|\s)
```

tested with grep:

```
kent$  echo "Tickets order: № 123123123. CED-MSW-RPG-MOW-CEK PODYLOVA/ALEMR 555 423578932 19OCT11 Tickets order: № 123123123. 346257. CSK-MOW-PRG-MOW-CWQ PODYLOVA/ALEMR 555 45837043 19OCT11"|grep -Po '(?<=-|\s)[A-Z]{3}(?=-|\s)' 
CED
MSW
RPG
MOW
CEK
CSK
MOW
PRG
MOW
CWQ
```

Comment: Does your variant uses nested groups as i asked?